# HDD problem, ntfs.sys - STOP on some location after boot

Tags: windows

I have two HDDs, one 250GB & a 500GB (both internal). 250GB HDD holds the OS (Windows XP). All of a sudden, my PC is landing on a bluescreen which says ntfs.sys - STOP & gives some address with datestamp after boot & windows XP screen. I removed 500GB drive & tried, everything works fine. This problem only occurs when I connect 500GB drive.

I googled & checked on other forums, all they say is run "CHKDSK /F". Well to run it, windows should load, which not happening! Both HDDs are detected when I check in BIOS. I tried Gparted to try fix things, but 500GB drive didn't get detected at all.

So, I'm clueless on how to fix the problem. Just hoping all my data is still safe on it.

Comment: You could find another computer with Windows (yes, they are a bit tricky to find nowadays but you'll manage eventually) and run `chkdsk` on your disk there.

Comment: You could post the actual error message. If you have a digital camera, that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally!!!!

Since I was unable to find other computer to plug in my HDD & run CHKDSK, I bought a HDD casing with USB connector. Plugged it in after windows loaded & found a problem in one partition. Run the CHKDSK [driveletter:] /F & it fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

boot from your winxp cd (when both drives are connected) and go to recovery console. There you can run chkdsk or mark the disk for being checked on next boot.

If your drive suddenly disappears you might want to run some HDD diagnostics tool from your disk manufacturer.

Comment: Tried getting into recovery mode, even that is not loading! It lands on the same bluescreen error page even in recovery mode!

Answer (score 0):

Is your 500GB disk showing up in BIOS or being detected by the computer at all?  It sounds like the 500GB is failing.

If the 500GB disk does not show up in BIOS any more then it may be a lost cause and the disk may totally be dead.

If the 500GB does show up in BIOS then maybe you could boot from a Ubuntu Live CD and then access the data. (The Ubuntu Live CD will make no changes to your working 250GB disk, so don't worry.) From the Ubuntu Live CD you could even move the data from the 500GB to another drive (even across the network) if you decide the 500GB needs to be replaced.

Good luck...

Comment: it is showing up in BIOS, but the problem is it won't show up when Gparted is booted from live CD! It also crashes windows if I plug it in as I already mentioned. Planning to plug it to some other computer & run CHKDSK